# Static file permissions with Nginx, Gunicorn and Django

Tags: nginx, django, gunicorn, static-files

I attempting to setup a Nginx server up with a Gunicorn WSGI server running Django behind..

The setup all seems to runs except i have a permissions issue. I have setup aliases to /media and a /static directory for serving up static content however a 403 error is generated unless the files are owned by the nginx user.

Files uploaded by the Gunicorn user will obviously be owned by that specific user which will cause a problem. I could add the nginx user to the gunicorn user group however i do not want to give nginx blanket permissions to these files.

What is the suggested method for uploading or generating files via Gunicorn/Wsgi/Django  but allow nginx to serve them without adding a security issue.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Blanket permissions to these files are not required. Nginx needs just a read permission. My nginx user account is `www-data`, gunicorn runs with `www_flask` privileges. Nginx serves all files uploaded from flask without problems.

File permissions `ls -lRr  /webroot`

```
/webroot:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 www_flask www_flask 4096 Jul  4 13:20 gunicorn

/webroot/gunicorn:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 www_flask www_flask 4096 Jul  4 14:57 uploads

/webroot/gunicorn/uploads:
total 924
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www_flask www_flask 164308 Jul  4 14:55 0001.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www_flask www_flask  53917 Jul  4 14:56 0004.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www_flask www_flask 349420 Jul  4 15:07 0005.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www_flask www_flask 365642 Jul  4 14:56 0006.jpg
```

nginx config

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / { 
        try_files $uri @gunicorn_proxy; 
    }   

    location /media {
        alias /webroot/gunicorn/uploads/;
    }   

    location @gunicorn_proxy {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }   
}
```

Flask upload example from tutorial `/home/www_flask/evironments/flask/myapp/myapp.py`

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/webroot/gunicorn/uploads'

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect('media/' + filename)
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
         <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like your directory or files are not set with read permissions for `others`.
You can, and should, run your application as a non-privileged user. You just need to give read permission to others:

```
chmod o+r -R /path/to/your/application
```